# Page refreshing automatically because of Turbolinks on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

On my rails app some of my pages get refreshed automatically without any apparent reasons. 
In my console i have this message :

> turbolinks.self-2db6ec539b9190f75e1d477b305df53d12904d5cafdd47c7ffd91ba25cbec128.js?body=1:7 You are loading Turbolinks from a  element inside the  element. This is probably not what you meant to do!
>
> Load your application’s JavaScript bundle inside the  element instead.  elements in  are evaluated with each page change.
>
> For more information, see: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#working-with-script-elements
>
> Suppress this warning by adding a `data-turbolinks-suppress-warning` attribute to: `<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-2db6ec539b9190f75e1d477b305df53d12904d5cafdd47c7ffd91ba25cbec128.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>`

When i comment my header partial in application.html.erb file the error message disappears but it's pretty basic

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Myleagueproject</title>
        <%= render "layouts/header" %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      </head>

  <body>
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my header :

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" style="background-color: black;">
    <% if player_signed_in? %>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <%= link_to root_path, class: 'header' do%>
                    Hi <%=current_player.name%>
                    <% end %>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto order-0">
            <%= image_tag("logo.png", :class => "logo", style: 'height:50px;width:auto;')%>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <%= link_to "My Leagues", leagues_path, class: 'header' %>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_player_session_path, method: :delete, class: 'header' %>  
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% else %>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">            
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <%= link_to "Log in", new_player_session_path, class: 'header' %>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I just don't get it, do you any idea what should i change ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Please include the contents of `"layouts/header"` for completeness

Comment: done max, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`<header>` elements are not permitted in the `<head>`, even though their names are similar.  The `<head>` is your document's head, where metadata, script, link, and title tags belong.  The `<header>` element represents introductory content in your document's `<body>` or one of its descendants.

I'd bet that this is what's causing the issue.  Move `<%= render "layouts/header" %>` to just beneath your opening `<body>` tag.

You can read more about the `<header>` tag and where it is permitted, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header

Comment: i have taken of <header> and it didn't change anything

Comment: Hm, I'd need to see the whole app then to figure it out.  Could be some other JS, or maybe whatever's loading in your action's template? If you could post a more complete picture, or share the code, that would be very helpful.